# Plot a set of 2d filed plots in a 3d plot using Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of 2d plots (Density of states (DOS) of atomic layers) and I want to plot them in a 3D plot to show how the DOS changes at each layer. 
My data is organized in a file (3D_data) in the following format

```
E1 Ly1 DOS11
E2 Ly1 DOS12
E3 Ly1 DOS13

E1 Ly2 DOS21
E2 Ly2 DOS22
E3 Ly2 DOS23
```

So far I have come up with the following gnuplot script

```
set xlabel "Energy - E_F (eV)"
set zlabel "Local DOS\n(states/eV)"
set xyplane 0
set view 60,50
set border 895
set style data lines
set surf
set yrange[0:20] noreverse nowriteback
set zrange[0:0.8] noreverse nowriteback
set xrange[-10:5] noreverse nowriteback
splot "3D_data" u 1:2:3 t "spin up"
```

This plots the data the way I want it. But now I want to apply a fillstyle to the curves like the curve in [this example (Transparent filled curves)](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.3/transparent.html). I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "fence plot". Just search for `fence plot gnuplot` on google.

Comment: Thanks psibar. It was a simple matter of adding "set style data impulses" to the above script

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about the impulses setting.  :)

Comment: Maybe answer your own question and leave this question answered? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution : add "set style data impulses" to the above script